# How to generate a equally distant point grid on a sphere?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, computational-geometry, spheres

I have a sphere (that is earth) and I would like to generate equally distant point all around it. so that it will looks like a grid :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8rp4.png]

I have a current code implementation where I use =>

```
s = 0
t = 0
(from t = 0 to t = 2PI)
   s = 0
   (from s = 0 to s = PI)
       x = cos(t) * sin(s)
       y = sin(t) * sin(s)
       z = cos(t)
   s += 0.1
t+= 0.1
```

[Exemple of my current code](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/#c=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)

The problem I have is The code is covering only a small part of earth, and the point are not really all equidistant, there is a higher density on the poles.

I was searching for multiple algorithms, but I don't find any to create equidistant point.

The next step after this would be to convert those lat/long point using [mercator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329691/convert-latitude-longitude-point-to-a-pixels-x-y-on-mercator-projection) to project them on a 2d map.

Comment: generating the point on the 2d map directly would also work, but I will need to find something to convert from 2d point to a long/lat point

Comment: As Charles says, you're trying to project a sphere without distortion, which is impossible. You may be interested in the [Mollweide projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide_projection), commonly used in astronomy, which exhibits less distortion near the poles. Unfortunately, you'll need to solve for an auxiliary angle numerically (I've used interpolation in the past)

Comment: There are more posts on MSE about this. The “spiral points” algorithm seems to be simple and quite effective. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating an equidistant point grid on a sphere, where the points are allowed to be arbitrarily close together, is impossible. This is the same problem as the map projection problem.

If we could generate a point grid of arbitrary fineness, we could convert the points to coordinates on the plane, creating a map projection with no distortion. It is known that no map projection exists that doesn't distort areas.

That said, probably your best option is to pass to a projection (one that minimizes area distortions for your region of interest), plot a grid a points, and convert those points back to coordinates on a sphere.

Comment: You might find [this](https://www.maths.unsw.edu.au/about/distributing-points-sphere) interesting as well.

Comment: Also, I should note that I'm using the word "area" somewhat freely. The precise statement is that there is no isometry between the sphere and plane. In fact, no open subset of the sphere is isometric to an open subset of the plane.